# Should one write window.X when referring to a built-in global property X in the (desktop) browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, window, global-variables

So, there are dozens of built-in global properties in the (desktop) browser. For instance:

- `document`
- `undefined`
- `parseInt`
- `JSON`
- `location`
- `alert`
- `setTimout`
- etc.

When referring to those properties, should one explicitly note them as global properties by prefixing their name with `window.`? So, for instance:

```
var wrap = window.document.getElementById('wrap');
```

and

```
window.setTimeout(loop, 100);
```

and

```
var x = window.parseInt(input.value, 10);
```

I think there are three answers to this question:

1. Yes, you should always write `window.X` when referring to global properties.
2. No, you don't have to write `window.X`. Just `X` is fine.
3. It depends on the property. For some properties, use `window.X`, for some other properties use `X`. (If this is your answer, please elaborate.)

So, which is it?

Comment: Well I have always used it without the `window` prefix. I would only use it when constructing something, like `window.something[name] = value;`. I would not say it is necessary.

Answer (score 9):

I would go for 3: no `window` except for a few exceptions.

In browsers, `window` refers to the global scope. `window.` as in `window.prompt()` is redundant. You could use it to emphasize that `prompt()` is a method of the `window` object.

I would never use something like `window.Math` or `window.NaN` because these properties are global objects that has nothing to do with the `window` object which is incidentally the global object in browsers. See also [Global Properties and Functions Defined in ECMAScript](http://www.herongyang.com/JavaScript/Built-In-Object-Global-Properties-and-Functions.html).

If you have another variable in the current (local) scope named `prompt`, you would need the `window.` prefix as well to get the prompt dialog as in:

```
(function() {
   var prompt = "Give me your name!";
   var name = window.prompt(prompt, "your name");
})();
```

For setting global variables, you should add the `window.` prefix as well to satisfy tools like [jslint](http://jslint.com). (otherwise, it would look like a you have forgotten the `var` keyword and thereby accidentally leaks a variable in the global scope):

```
(function() {
   // "WRONG"
   somevar = 1;
   // You probably want to set a local variable, so should use:
   var somevar = 1;
   // take away the confusion, you really wanted to set a global variable:
   window.somevar = 1;
})();
```

Generally, omitting `window.` improves readability, considering the next example:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
   var numA = window.parseInt(window.document.getElementById("numA").value, 10);
   var numB = window.parseInt(window.document.getElementById("numB").value, 10);
   window.document.getElementById("avg").value = window.Math.floor((numA + numB) / 2);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: My question is only about the built-in global properties in the browsers. Using `window.X` when setting user-defined global properties is OK, however it is off-topic. As for your other exception - accessing global properties that are shadowed by local variables - this is a valid point.

Comment: @Sime Vidas: In that case, the answer is complete. It's a matter of personal taste, the language allows both ways. There is no definitive answer, although arguments can be given to make decisions.

Answer (score 2):

Normally unless I'm dubious about people overwriting known global variables with local names I use `X` directly instead of referring to it as `window.X`.

However for `Setter` situations rather then `Getter` situations I like to use `window.X` to illustrate that I'm hoisting a particular variable into global scope.

Ideally I like having everything event & callback driven and limiting setting variables into global scope.

```
(function($, undefined) {
    ...
    var SomeUsefulConstruct = function() { 
         ...
    }
    ...
    // hoist to global scope
    window.SomeUsefulConstruct = SomeUsefulConstruct;
    ...
}(jQuery);
```

Sticking to this pattern of using `window.X` you can make it very clear when your setting data on a global level. In an ideal situations you can use no globals at all what so ever apart from and using a set of callbacks and event handlers instead.

Comment: Using the `window.X` notation when setting new global properties sounds reasonable. However, note that my question is about the built-in global properties in the browsers, not the ones that we declare additionally.

Comment: @SimeVidas I abstracted your question to when to use `window.`. In my opinion 2 coupled with never declare a local variable that overwrites a known native global variable. so `var name` and `var location` are disallowed.

Comment: I agree with that. Local variables should not shadow global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'll take **(3)**, though I think **(2)** is a fine answer also.  My reason is that some objects aren't really part of the global environment that happens to be a browser window.  It just seems weird to write `window.Math.floor(n)` because "Math" is there in the spec as being a standard built-in thing. However, "top" or "document" are peculiar to a particular kind of global context, so it seems more meaningful to use the "window" qualifier.

(My own actual practice is somewhere in between; I tend to use "window" explicitly for things that I'm simply used to thinking about that way.  It does break down mostly as I wrote above, however.)

Comment: Can you give some examples for what global properties you use the `window.X` notation?

Answer (score 0):

answer is 2, until you are not sure if in your current scope `setTimeout` function (for example) wasn't overriden by a 'local' function. moreover, in some environments, `window` object may not be present (or may be something else).

there's also a good practice which suggests not to access `window` object directly, because in various host environments it may be called differently. there's a patten in which you create a variable which references to `this` called from 'outer' (global) scope, because it's guaranteed by specs to always return top-level object. example usage:

```
(function(global){
    // ... your code
})(this);
```

Comment: Note that I explicitly stated "in the browsers" in the title of my question - so there is no question that the `window` object is present.

Comment: @Sime, ah, right. anyway, browser is a vast term, I remember PPK saying something about `window` being inaccessible on some-strange-mobile-device. (can't find sources now)

Comment: Good point. Iv'e changed my question to make it clear that I'm interested in desktop browsers specifically.

Answer (score -1):

There is one tricky case - the window.name attribute. For example, with the code

```
name = "myWindow";
```

the `window.name` property is changed in IE and Chrome thus the `<a target=myWindow>` would open in the same window in these browsers, and in new window in Firefox and Opera. In this case, always use `window.name` notation for cross-browser functionality.

The best practice is to use `window.X` only when X is really the property of `window`. Don't use `window.Infinity` because there is no `'Infinity' in Window.prototype`.

Comment: There is also no `name` in `DOMWindow`. You probably mean there is no `Infinity` on the window object. `Infinity` lives in global scope. There is an annoying over lap between the `window` object and the global scope `window`.

Comment: @duri So for what properties specifically would you use `window.X`? Can you post some examples?

Comment: @Šime Vidas For everything except global objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects However, in most cases `window.` is not necessary and using just `X` would give the same results (`alert()` and so on).

Comment: @duri I don't understand your response. You mean all global properties that are not objects (like `undefined` and `name`)?

Comment: @Šime Vidas `undefined` is also listed in the list at MDC (under the "Other" section), so in this case you shouldn't use `window.`. `name` is just property of `window`, so I recommend `window.name` notation.

Comment: @duri So let me repeat myself: for what properties specifically would you use `window.X`? Can you post some examples?

Comment: @Šime Vidas Some examples are `window.name`, `window.addEventListener`, `window.alert`, `window.scrollTo`, `window.parent` - these are all properties of the `window` object.

Comment: @duri So, you would use `window.alert` instead of `alert`? Also, what about `document` or `setTimeout`? Would you use `window.` for those also?

Comment: @Šime Vidas Theoretically, it would be more correct way (also applies to `window.document` and `window.setTimeout`). However, in most cases it doesn't matter (`window.name` is an exception because it behaves unpredictably if you use only `name`). The more important thing is not to use `window` where it shouldn't be used (e.g. `NaN`, `encodeURIComponent`, `Infinity`).

Comment: @duri Why shouldn't `window.NaN` be used (in a desktop browser environment)?