# extend the json object javascript

Tags: javascript

javascript code:

```
window.mybooks={"books": [{"name":"book one","author":"Samuel Peter"},{"name":"book two","author":"Samuel Anderson"}]};
```

How to add new book to window.mybooks ?

```
{"name":"book three","author":"Samuel Abelson"}
```

**UPDATE:**

strange , a lot of same answers, and not working for me... what can cause this ?

I did found that the object is generated, maybe incorrectly. It looks like this:

```
window.mybooks={"books": [{"name":"book one","author":"Samuel Peter"},{"name":"book two","author":"Samuel Anderson"},]};
```

any hints how to correct it and mayabe then push will work ?

Comment: You mean like window.mybooks.books.push(new_book)?

Comment: This isn't JSON!  It's just a JavaScript object.  JSON is a *string representation* of data, used for transport.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
window.mybooks.books.push({"name":"book three","author":"Samuel Abelson"});
```

Comment: No need for the explicit `window.` prefix when accessing that object.

Comment: see how many votes one can get for answer a simple question with a simple answer, lol +1 \o/

Comment: @RocketHazmat No. Doing it to be safe would be a bad practice. If one creates global variables, he should make them distinguishable (e.g. all caps), and *never* shadow them. The `window.` prefix makes sense for global variables that represent properties of the Window object (e.g. `window.name`). This is not such a case.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: What tells you that he is specifically on a browser? His start had `window.`, I gave it to him using `window.`. After all, he could be using Node and `window` could very well be a local var in this case. Prefer explicit definitions wherever the context is not known.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Also, sorry to break it to you: `k = "test"; console.log(window.k);`. Try this. In a browser environment, `window` is **the** global scope in addition to being the `window` object.

Comment: @Jigberto: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/LrKNY/ . Might want to build your own fiddle to show us how your code runs, exactly.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Browser context is implied. Node env with `window` being local var is as unlikely as it gets (not worth assuming). When creating global variables, `window.foo = value;` is a common approach as it works from within any scope (unlike `var foo = value;` which has to appear in global code in order to create a global variable). Once the global variable is created, my suggestion is that one accesses it *directly*, i.e. with `foo` rather than `window.foo`. The `window.` prefix is best left to imply a connection with the browser’s window, like with `window.name`…

Comment: @SébastienRenauld The global variables created by web applications don’t imply a connection to the browser’s window. Instead, they just happen to be global variables. For instance, you don’t access the jQuery object with `window.$` but rather with just `$`. That’s because there is no implied connection with the browser’s window here. On the other hand, the `name` global variable *does* have a connection to the browser’s window as it represents the name of that window. So, one uses `window.name` rather then `name` to imply that connection.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld I've asked [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5460593/425275) some time ago.

Answer (score 7):

Use [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

```
var newBook = {"name":"book three","author":"Samuel Abelson"};
mybooks.books.push(newBook );
```

If you are not in the window context the explicitly use `window.mybooks.books.push(newBook);`

Answer (score 1):

```
var newBook = {
    "name": "book three",
    "author": "Samuel Abelson"
};
mybooks.books.push(newBook);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var newBook = {"name":"book three","author":"Samuel Abelson"};
mybooks.books.push(newBook);
```

Try this it should work. Use `Javascript Array.push`

Answer (score -1):

```
window.mybooks={"books": [{"name":"book one","author":"Samuel Peter"},{"name":"book two","author":"Samuel Anderson"}]};
```

This is a json object, so here is a function:

```
const addBook(json, key, childObj) {
  const obj = JSON.parse(json)
  obj[key].push(childObj)
  return JSON.stringify(obj)
}
```

To use it

```
window.mybooks = addBook(window.mybooks, books, {name: "book three", author: "William Shakespeare"})
```

---

Now, the question mentioned extending the JSON object.

I'm not sure that was what you meant, bit it's not possible to extend JSON because, up until today, it's not a class but a readonly Javascript interface in the vanilla API.

Even if it was possible to extend it, this function wouldn't work on all JSON strings, only on yours.

**EDIT:** this doesn't work. it's not json. my mistake.

Comment: No, it's not JSON, and `JSON.parse` won't work