# window.setTimeout vs setTimeout? which one is better?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

ive been using timeout without the window parent like this:

```
setTimeout(FUNC, 1000);
```

And i was curious, should i be using it like this?

```
window.setTimeout(FUNC, 1000);
```

is there a difference?
i haven't noticed a difference when using it without the window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should one write window.X when referring to a built-in global property X in the (desktop) browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460593/should-one-write-window-x-when-referring-to-a-built-in-global-property-x-in-the)

Answer (score 6):

This can be answered very easily:

`window.setTimeout === setTimeout` will be `true`

`window` is the global scope in the browser. If your code needs to be portable to non-browser environments, the more specific `window.setTimeout` will fail.

Comment: Oh, is that so for all webbrowsers?

Comment: Oh thank you :D! wait 11 mins and ill choose your answer thxx i didnt know it was a global scope